# Changing the most significant bit in a int16

Tags: php

I want to encode an int16 value in 15 bits and leave the leftmost bit as a flag. Then I want to read the bytes and decode to decimal the rightmost 15 bits as the integer. Is this possible?

```
$value = 49;
$packed = pack('S', $value); // returns correct hex
$formatted = $packed ^ 0b1000000000000000; // returns too long number - 4 bytes instead of 2
```

How can I do this?

Comment: php doesn't have different sized ints. they're all 32bit of 64bit, depending on the underlying platform, and they're all signed integers as well. you can't fiddle with the high bit directly, and still have that value be treated as a php int, because that's the sign bit, and not something you should be messing with directly.

Comment: I dont want to keep them in PHP, I want to write it to file.

Comment: you did a bitwise operation, which returns an integer, which got expanded up to the underlying system's int size, which is 32bit (4 bytes) in your case. do the packing when you're FINISHED manipulating that value, and are about to output it. and even then you might get tripped up by php auto-converting it yet again.

Comment: Oooooh...hm, so there's no way to operate on bits directly?

Answer (score 0):

Use [bitwise](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) operators.

You have got your number in to `$packed`.

Let the `$encoded` be your target.

Save the `$packed` to the `$encoded`

```
$encoded = $packed;

$encoded = $encoded | 0b1000000000000000;   //Set the MSB
```

Lets read it back

```
$encoded = $encoded $ 0b0111111111111111;   //Clear the MSB first
$packed = $encoded;                         //The rest is automatically the value
```

Comment: Hm, it still saves the numbers as 32 bit, instead of 16 bit. `$packed = Convertion :: to16int($value);
    $packed = $packed | 0b1000000000000000;
    $buffer .= $packed;`

Comment: You can make all the leading bits zero and interpret the value of it through this algorithm.